# Kotlin-extensions all synthetic imports unresolved

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin-android-extensions

Suddenly all `synthetic` imports in my project became unresolved. I guess after deleting and reverting some layout file.

Project **successfully builds**, but everything is red and auto completion doesn't work.

What i've tried

- Build/Clean Project / Build/Rebuild Project
- Invalidate cache & Restart
- Sync Gradle
- Delete .gradle
- Delete .idea

Versions

- AS 4.0
- Kotlin 1.3.72

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved by deleting whole project and importing from version control.